# Как скачать файл через командную строку/VBS-скрипт без использования сторонних утилит?

Tags: файлы, cmd, bat, vbscript, download

Как скачать файл через командную строку/VBS-скрипт без использования сторонних утилит, т.е. без wget, curl и т.д.? Очень нужно скачать файл по прямой ссылке (протокол HTTP) именно встроенными средствами ОС Windows. Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Откуда хоть качать-то... ну или хотя бы какой протокол... ну и само собой, что за файл - а то счас окажется, что это веб-страница, вся сверху донизу в скриптах...

Comment: @Akina нужно скачать exe-файл по прямой ссылке, протокол HTTP.

Comment: не часто используют [bitsadmin](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/bitsadmin-examples), который появился ещё при Windows XP: `bitsadmin /transfer myjob /download /priority normal http://www.dist.com/files/dist.iso C:\Users\User\Downloads\distr.iso`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**bat.cmd**

```
@Echo Off

Set ROOT=C:/test

Set KBFile1=logo.png
Set KB_Url1=http://www.oszone.net/figs/logo.png

Set KBFile2=logo2.png
Set KB_Url2=http://www.oszone.net/figs/logo.png

Call :KB_TEST "%KBFile1%" "%KB_Url1%"
Call :KB_TEST "%KBFile2%" "%KB_Url2%"

Echo.
PAUSE

EXIT

:KB_TEST
<Nul Set /P $_X="%~1..."

If Exist "%ROOT%\%~1" Echo Ok& Exit /B
<Nul Set /P $_X=Loading

CScript //NoLogo "%~dpn0.vbs" "%ROOT%\%~1" "%~2"
Set ERR=%ErrorLevel%

<Nul Set /P $_X=Complete
If %ERR% EQU 0 (Echo Ok     ) Else Echo ERROR  

Exit /B
```

**bat.vbs**

```
If Wscript.Arguments.Count=2 Then
    WScript.Quit(HTTPFileGet(Wscript.arguments.Item(1), Wscript.arguments.Item(0)))
Else
    WScript.Quit(1)
End If

Function HTTPFileGet(strFileURL, strFileSave)
    Dim objXMLHTTP, objADOStream, objFSO
    HTTPFileGet = 1

    Set objXMLHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
    Set objADOStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
    Set objFSO = Createobject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    objXMLHTTP.Open "GET", strFileURL, False
    objXMLHTTP.Send

    If objXMLHTTP.Status = 200 Then
        objADOStream.Open
        objADOStream.Type = 1

        objADOStream.Write objXMLHTTP.ResponseBody
        objADOStream.Position = 0

        If objFSO.FileExists(strFileSave) Then objFSO.DeleteFile strFileSave

        objADOStream.SaveToFile strFileSave
        objADOStream.Close

        HTTPFileGet = 0
    End If
End Function
```

**Источник:** http://forum.oszone.net/post-1260131-4.html

Answer (score -3):

```
pip install "href to file"
```

Comment: какое отношение к вопросу имеет то, что вы написали?